# I have dual booted my hp laptop and now having BIOS issues

Tags: dual-boot, bios

I dual booted my Hp G3 8GB RAM. Now I'm having trouble while opening a laptop every time it is switched on(screen turns black and nothing shows up). Have to try multiple times to turn it on. I asked the technician and he said the problem is with the bios. Should I delete ubuntu or is there any alternative? I do not want to delete it.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. And is HP-G315 the complete model #?

Comment: It's HP Elitebook 820 G3

Comment: Bios version: N75 Ver. 01.33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

HP Elitebook 820 G3

You have BIOS version 01.33.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 01.47 Rev.A, dated 5/11/2020, and it can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-820-g3-notebook-pc/7815289).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: Thank you for finding out time to help. Will surely check it out :)

Comment: @MaleehaKhalid Please let me know if it solves the problem.